# I am getting an error of: not enough values to unpack (Expected 2, got 1) im following a tutorial but it just wont work

Tags: python, syntax

This is the code I have used from a tutorial

```
def view():
    with open('My coding stuff\\passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User:",user, ", password:", passw)
```

I have no idea what is wrong with the code
I was trying to make a password manager by following a tutorial and i am just confused

Comment: It looks like your txt file does not have text items separated by |. Try printing it out after reading it in.

Comment: Try looking at the value of `data`.  Add `print(data)` after assigning to it.  The problem line does not contain a `|`, so `data.split("|")` is producing a list of length 1.  This causes the assignment to `user, passw` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please save data in password.txt in below format

User|pwd

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code that you are assigning one value in tuple `user, passw` instead of 2 values which is returned by `data.split("|")`.

I think that the file you are reading doesn't contain data in the format `user | pass` (each record seperated by `|` ) so it gives you this exception Error.
I suggest to check the format of data in your file then edit your code according to it.